# Cannot receive APNS while app is Killed

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, apple-push-notifications

I am working on a iOS app with xamarin. Now I got this problem, I want to send Push Notifications from a server to connected devices. I can receive these notifications when my app is running & when my app is in the background. Now the problem is, can I receive notifications when my app is Killed? ( Home button swipe up)? I read about it and it should be possible though not reliable. But still, how do I do it?

I read about getting the notification via the launchoptions

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
```

but it's allways Null & there is no way to debug it since I'm closing my app.
Any thoughts about what I am doing wrong?

P.S. I am using a development provisioning profile (maybe this is the problem?)

Edit 1: Extra info (code)

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        application.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes (UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound);

        if (launchOptions != null)
        {
            // check for a local notification
            if (launchOptions.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey))
            {
                var localNotification = launchOptions[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
                if (localNotification != null)
                {

                    new UIAlertView("TESTER", "TESTER3", null, "OK", null).Show();
                    // reset our badge
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (deviceToken.ToString ());
        String tokenStr = deviceToken.Description;
        var deviceToken1 = tokenStr.Replace ("<", "").Replace (">", "").Replace (" ", "");
        ViewController.deviceToken = deviceToken1;
    }

    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification (UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Recieved");
        var message = userInfo.ValueForKey (new NSString ("aps")).ValueForKey (new NSString ("message")).ToString ();
        var reload = userInfo.ValueForKey (new NSString ("aps")).ValueForKey (new NSString ("refreshList")).ToString ();
        var vehicleId = userInfo.ValueForKey (new NSString ("aps")).ValueForKey (new NSString ("vehicleListId")).ToString ();
    }
```

==> Do stuff with the 3 vars (with info)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, may sure that all your certs are correct (eg: use development cert for sandbox server, user production cert for production server)

Secondly, you will need to handle the push notification in 2 different methods. I am not sure the code in C# or Xamarin, the code in Objective-C is as below:-

```
//Receive Push Notification when the app is active in foreground or background
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
           didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

  if(userInfo){
   //TODO: Handle the userInfo here
   }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Get the push notification when app is not open
    NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if(remoteNotif){
        [self handleRemoteNotification:application userInfo:remoteNotif];
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)handleRemoteNotification:(UIApplication*)application userInfo:(NSDictionary*)userInfo{

    if(userInfo){
       //TODO: Handle the userInfo here
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear, thank you for your answer! I am using the correct certificates, since I can receive notifications when the app is running / background. & So far I see, I have the same implementation you have.
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    if (launchOptions != null) {
        //Do something

& I have a received remoteNotification
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification (UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)

Comment: hm... if your implementation is exactly the same like mine, then I really have no idea where the problem is. You might have to post more information in order for other people to understand your problem better.

Comment: I have edited my question with the code I have at the moment. Hope this clears it out a bit.

Comment: I want to understand better. When your app is killed, you send a notification from your server, what do you see? Do you receive the notification? If yes, what do you do next? You tap the notification to go to the app or you tap the app directly?

Comment: That's the problem, I do not receive anything when my app is killed. I only receive notifications when my app is on the foreground / background (so running). But I don't receive anything when my app is killed.